# Unable to use jQuery with server-side Rails widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, widget

I'm creating a widget, for which I have initialized jQuery like so:

```
# widget.js
(function() {
  var jQuery;
  var root_url = "<%= root_url%>";

  if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.9.1') {
    var jquery_script   = document.createElement('script');
    jquery_script.type  = "text/javascript";
    jquery_script.asyc  = true;
    jquery_script.src   = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js";  

    if (jquery_script.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
        }
      };
    } else { // Other browsers
      jquery_script.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }

    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(jquery_script, node); 
  } else {    
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main(); 
  }

  function scriptLoadHandler() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    main(); 
  }

  function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      // jQuery works great here!
      // But not so much in rendered partials or in server-side JS actions
    }
  }
})();
```

If I make an ajax request to my server and respond with a JS action, I can't use jQuery in my `action.js.erb` file. It spits out the error `$ is not a function`.

Similarly, even rendering partials with jQuery scripts in them yields the same results.

I think I haven't set a global instance of jQuery, and if this is the case, I'm not sure how to do that. Perhaps I'm not supposed to?

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: i think its because you are using jquery.noconflict, when you use this the $ sign becomes unusable, no longer aliased

Comment: @Richlewis hmm really? I think you may be onto something. I never considered this. How, then, would I rectify other instances of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't what I was looking for but I was able to combine elements of the native JS widget with an iframe. Once I manipulate whatever elements I need to on the 3rd party site (as per my widget's functionality) I render a partial housing an iframe that lets me completely control the environment.